# Cuáles serían las formas de modelización para Identificar clientes mediante la aplicación de leyes de polarización

Tags: machine-learning, redes-neuronales

Inspirándose en el enfoque del físico **Michele Starnini** (*Universidad Politécnica de Cataluña*) sobre estudios de física aplicada para explicar fenómenos sociales, empezaré a codificar un modelo que mida la fuerza de opinión de los individuos basándose en la exposición directa a las opiniones.
Me gustaría saber cómo conseguir data relacionada para no recurrir a sintetización de datos.